# App must be inserted into the docker image?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile

I read a lot of documentation and tutorials about docker and a configuration compatible with the development in dev and deploy into production.

I found different approaches about the inclusion of the app (in my case Node.js API server) inside the docker image, and they are:

- create `Dockerfile` within the app and copy the application itself inside docker (`ADD. / src`)
- **not include** the `Dockerfile` in repo app, but in a separate repo and run a script that performs a series of tasks, such as clone the repo app, launch the task for build ...

Which of the solutions is to be preferred?
What are the pros and cons of the two approaches?

It must take into account that my aim is to create a configuration that can be deployed to an inside elastic beanstalk AWS

Comment: There is also another approach, which is to mount the app as a volume at run time. The mounting approach does not require you to build a new image every time you update your app (unless dependency changes).

Comment: @warmoverflow thanks for the info. What kind of configuration should be used with this type of approach, if I have to deploy in aws? Some examples?

Comment: Sorry but I have no experience with AWS Bean Stalk itself, the suggestion is just from the perspective of Docker. There is an example on this page http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_image.html which defines a volume in the json file, which is similar to what I meant by mounting a volume.